No Trusted Certificate Found When Connecting to Snowflake
My connection to Snowflake was working just fine prior to recently. Suddenly I'm getting the error:
JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: No trusted certificate found.
when trying to connect using DBeaver. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

There was a certificate authority change recently. Have a look at the following link and see if that helps:
"Change of Certificate Authority and OCSP Allowlist for AWS Customers"
